# Prevent system not to "sleep" so cron can run each minute (with 0 users)

Tags: server, suspend, cron

I have a crontab that works properly except when the system "sleeps" (or something I don't understand). To debug what is happening I added this cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * uptime>>uptimeDebug.txt
```

This is the result:

```
14:19:01 up 7 days,  1:27,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
14:20:01 up 7 days,  1:28,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
14:21:01 up 7 days,  1:29,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
14:22:01 up 7 days,  1:30,  0 users,  load average: 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
14:42:01 up 7 days,  1:50,  0 users,  load average: 0,04, 0,01, 0,00
15:06:01 up 7 days,  2:14,  1 user,  load average: 0,04, 0,01, 0,00
15:07:01 up 7 days,  2:15,  1 user,  load average: 0,01, 0,01, 0,00
```

As you can see there is a jump from 14:22 to 14:42. The system is a server (tower desktop computer) properly connected to power. I don't understand what the system is doing during that period of time. I need to run some jobs at certain moments with cron, but, please, how can I prevent the system this "sleep"?

This sleep time is not always the same at the same hour. It depends on the number of users that are connected to the system. The system is a PHP Server running a small/toy homemade html app.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the logs in `/var/log/`, to see what's going on between 14:42:01 and 15:06:01. `dategrep`, from `https://travis-ci.org/mdom/dategrep` will help.

Comment: Do you use encryption of any type? Cron cannot read encrypted data when you are logged out.